# Is there a way to use tortoise svn to backup my modified files?

Tags: tortoisesvn, backup

I have a bunch of files that I've changed that I don't really want to commit, but I would like to back them up locally in case I would like to use them again.  (Then I'll revert them.)

TortoiseSvn working status helps to view the modified files, but I want a way to save them all to a separate directory like Backups\, preferably with their folder heirararchy still in tact.

How can I do that?

---

**UPDATE:**

Apparently branching is the way to go.

But what I did was just copied the modified files paths to the clipboard (which is an option in tortoisesvn) then to a file, and created a program to copy them to a backup folder.

Comment: Thx for posting you resolution. It's always good to know how you finalize it.

Comment: Thanks TridenT.  Appreciation appreciated.  Unfortunately there is no accept multiple solutions button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create a branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html) and commit those files only in that branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can commit it inside a branch, so it doesn't affect your current 'trunk' or branch.

If you had a try with [bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) , that is compatible with SVN, there is a [shelf](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-reference/shelve-help.html) command to temporarily store a set of modification and apply back them later.